# The Union Ain't Jack

Tags: word, visual, rebus

Each line is a clue to a different word, take each of the n'th letters to get a final word that relates all the clues. Have a picture!

[image: Pictures on a Union Jack]

Comment: Couldn't you find a real British Jay?  :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think it's going to be

> Brexit

but I'm still stuck on the first one.

> 1: boar eyes jay on sun = Boris Johnson, 1st letter is B
>  2: art eye call five tea = Article Fifty, 2nd letter is r
>  3: tear e's a may(pole) = Theresa May, 3rd letter is e
>  4: fl(y)(t)ux = flux, 4th letter is x
>  5: ream+Maine = remain, 5th letter is i
>  6: mark-ET axe-s = market access, 6th letter is t

(Thanks to dcfyj for suggesting Maine, and Lukas Rotter for getting "access", in Sphinx's Lair chat. It turns out BeastlyGerbil was independently finding the latter here while we were discussing it there.)

Comment: Well you know one starts with b

Comment: And I think that the second part is Jay On Sun

Comment: yeah, I know, but it would be nice to work the whole thing out.

Comment: First is Boris Johnson

Comment: yeah, I was just getting there :-)

Comment: Still confused about the last one, though. Ticket axes? Ticket hatchets?

Comment: Tickboxes? Or Ticket Boxes? Not sure

Comment: I think its Market Acces = Mark Et Axes

Comment: I feel like the 6th letter isn't 5. ;)